# Arduino AREF parpadea

Tags: php, arduino, serialport

Tengo un codigo en php muy sencillo de dos botones, uno para encender y otro apagar el led.

Un codigo en arduino muy sencillo igualmente.

Mi problema es, usando la consola del ide de arduino el programa va bien, sin fallos, pero a la hora de controlarlo por php simplemente parpadea 2 veces el aref y el led 13, ajdunto los codigos.

PHP

```
$comPort = "/dev/ttyACM0";
if (isset($_POST["rcmd"])) {
$rcmd = $_POST["rcmd"];
switch ($rcmd) {
     case On:
        $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
  fwrite($fp, H); 
  fclose($fp);
  break;
     case Off:
        $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
  fwrite($fp, L); 
  fclose($fp);
  break;
}
```

Y Arduino:

```
const int ledPin = 13; // the pin that the LED is attached to - change this if you have a separate LED connected to another pin
int incomingByte;      // a variable to read incoming serial data into
```

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // see if there's incoming serial data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the oldest byte in the serial buffer:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    // if it's a capital H (ASCII 72), turn on the LED:
    if (incomingByte == 'H') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    // if it's an L (ASCII 76) turn off the LED:
    if (incomingByte == 'L') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Deberías agregar tu código PHP. Saludos.

Comment: Error mio, se perdio al poner el formato, lo corrijo ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné mi problema, dejo la solucion/información ṕor si alguien en un futuro llegase a requerirla.

Resulta que al arduino dejar de recibir datos por el serial port, entra en modo sleep, entonces se busca una forma de evitar esto, una forma que funciono para mi es colocar un capacitor de 22microFaradios de la entrada "Reset" a "gnd", existen mas soluciones mencionadas en este post:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection

Comment: Así de sencillo y ya funciona normalmente? Es que me pasó que enchufé con un cable de router el arduino, para ver si así llegaba más corriente, y des de ahí des de el arduino ide funciona, pero desde el php no. (Antes de enchufarlo a la corriente funcionaba todo correctamente)